# Extract RABL nodes from collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I want to add some meta data about the response in my JSON output, but RABL insert them inside the handled collection. Here is my template:

**views/clients/show.rabl**

```
node(:status) { response.status }
node(:time) { Time.now }

collection @client
attributes :name, :base_url, :city
attribute c_at: :created_at

node(:items_count) { |c| c.items.count }
node(:users_count) { |c| c.users.count }
```

This gives me the following JSON response:

```
{"client":{"status":200,"time":"2015-04-16 13:45:46 +0200","name":"This is a test","base_url":"http://test.com","city":"Paris","created_at":"2015-04-15 10:38:44 UTC","items_count":3,"users_count":0}}
```

Here, `status` and `time` information are inside the `client` collection. How can I extract them, to have the following output:

```
{"time":"...","status":200,"client":{...}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The magic comes with `object false`. Here is the answer.

```
object false

node(:status) { response.status }
node(:time) { Time.now }

child @client do
  attributes :name, :base_url, :city
  attribute c_at: :created_at

  node(:items_count) { |c| c.items.count }
  node(:users_count) { |c| c.users.count }
end
```

Hope it will help.